# Как выбрать данные из двух таблиц с использованием синонимов (алиасов колонок)

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, codeigniter, join

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Есть две таблицы

sku  (люди):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

strana (страны)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

- c_idget -  страны покупатели
- c_idgive -  страны продавцы

обе эти колонки ссылаются на id стран из таблицы strana

мне нужно собрать один общий массив в котором будет видно и id стран продавцов и id стран покупателей, а так же названия стран продавцов и названия стран покупателей

примерно он должен выглядеть так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 1
            [c_idgive] => 1
            [c_idget] => 2
            [scu_name] => Иван
            [c_namegive] => Россия
            [c_nameget] => Украина
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 2
            [c_idgive] => 3
            [c_idget] => 2
            [scu_name] => Петр
            [c_namegive] => Беларусь
            [c_nameget] => Украина
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 3
            [c_idgive] => 3
            [c_idget] => 3
            [scu_name] => Сергей
            [c_namegive] => Беларусь
            [c_nameget] => Беларусь         
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 4
            [c_idgive] => 1
            [c_idget] => 3
            [scu_name] => Анатолий
            [c_namegive] => Россия
            [c_nameget] => Беларусь         
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 5
            [c_idgive] => 5
            [c_idget] => 4
            [scu_name] => Александр
            [c_namegive] => Азербайджан
            [c_nameget] => Казахстан            
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 6
            [c_idgive] => 3
            [c_idget] => 2
            [scu_name] => Борис
            [c_namegive] => Беларусь
            [c_nameget] => Украина      
        )
)
```

пробовал через join используя конструктор запросов фреймверка

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sku');
$this->db->join('strana','sku.c_idget = strana.c_id');
$this->db->join('strana','sku.c_idgive = strana.c_id');
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return($query);
```

но получал ошибку

> Not unique table/alias: 'strana'

понял что два джоина вместе использовать нельзя

читал, что можно сделать как-то алиасы колонок, чтобы в массив попадало сразу две страны просто ключи в массиве имели бы разные названия (те, которые я задам через `AS`), но в лучшем случае у меня удалось перезаписать одну страну другой, но так чтобы вывести обе, у меня не получилось.

помогите сформировать рабочий запрос.

мне достаточно будет и обычного sql запроса лишь бы работало)

гуглил, лазил на англоязычных форумах. но рабочего результата не добился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так?

```
SELECT
    sku.s_id,        # Выбираем поле s_id из таблицы sku
    sku.c_idgive,    # Выбираем поле c_idgive из таблицы sku
    sku.c_idget,     # Выбираем поле c_idget из таблицы sku
    sku.scu_name,    # Выбираем поле scu_name из таблицы sku
    (                # создаём подзапрос в SELECT для города продавца
    SELECT
        c_name       # Выбираем название города
    FROM
        strana       # из таблицы стран
    WHERE
        strana.c_id = sku.c_idgive  # Где id (c_id) страны равен (c_idgive) стране продавцу
) AS c_namegive,  # присваиваем псевдоним выборке (c_namegive)
(                 # создаём подзапрос в SELECT для города продавца
    SELECT
        c_name   # Выбираем название города
    FROM
        strana    # из таблицы стран
    WHERE
        strana.c_id = sku.c_idget # Где id (c_id) страны равен (c_idget) стране покупателю
) AS c_nameget # присваиваем псевдоним выборке (c_nameget)
FROM
    sku   # Основная выборка
```

Comment: По идее, если вставить этот запрос в phpmyadmin он мне должен выдать результат. Попробую..  Вроде бы тут понятнее,  ещё бы комментарий и я вроде бы читал что джоины нужны.  А тут совсем без них обошлись, а что есть альтернатива с джоинами?

Comment: В предыдущем ответе использовали *. Я так понимаю чтобы притягивать первую таблицу к таблице которая свормируется из выборки по двум колонкам,  а здесь это можно как то сделать, чтобы сократить запись и не перечислять вся колонки из первой таблицы? Ну и ещё если мне нужно будет вытащить все колонки из второй таблицы то в каком месте это переслять (например если захочу вытащить c_id,  или ещё какую то если бы она там была

Comment: В таблице sku используется два поля(c_idgive и c_idget) для одной таблицы. Поэтому(я так считаю) джоины тут бесполезны. Можно их использовать, но код будет слишком громоздким по моему скромному мнению. 
Возможно найдутся люди которые думают иначе.

Comment: В предыдущем запросе использовали sku.* для того, чтобы сделать выборку по всем столбцам. Я это сделал специально для наглядности. Вы можете делать как Вам удобно.

Comment: "Ну и ещё если мне нужно будет вытащить все колонки из второй таблицы то в каком месте это переслять (например если захочу вытащить c_id, или ещё какую то если бы она там была"

При каких условиях? Не понимаю. Зачем вытаскивать c_id если этот c_id указан в таблице sku в колонках c_idgive, c_idget ?

Comment: Добавил комментарии.

Comment: Да просто колонок мало.. Например если бы у меня ещё была колонка population (количество человек проживающих в стране) и main_language,  к примеру.. Спасибо ваш ответ очень помог.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Делаете по той же схеме что и с «(SELECT c_name FROM strana WHERE strana.c_id = sku.c_idgive) AS c_namegive» – вместо c_name пишите другую интересующую Вас колонку предварительно добавив её в таблицу "strana" .

Answer (score 1):

По идее,

```
select sku.*, get.c_name as c_nameget, give.c_name as c_namegive from (sku inner join strana get on sku.idget=get.c_id) inner join strana give on sku.idgive=give.c_id
```

Comment: А можно как то построчно отдельно разбить. И объяснить где что делается?  а то если вдруг неправильно то и не пойму в каком месте править, а если верно то просто решу задачу но понимания не будет. Соответственно, в будущем снова зайду в тупик

Comment: Особенно интересно почему после from скобки,  потом их нет,  и почему без left? С ним тоже как то можно?

Comment: Построчно можете разбить и сами, произвольным образом. Скобки потому что двойная операция: в арифметике можно писать a+b+c, а тут только (a+b)+c. left нет, потому что нужен именно inner join — или у вас могут встречаться, к примеру, c_idgive, которому не соответствует c_id в таблице стран?

Comment: нет, такого нет